# Token generated using twitter fabric gives authentication error code 32

Tags: android, node.js, twitter

While playing around with the twitter new Fabric sdk I did the following.

1. Created a TwitterLoginButton as described in the documentation.
2. Got the auth_token and auth_secret in this process.
3. Tried using this auth token and secret in one my nodejs app to post tweet but this gives me an error saying

   Could not authenticate you - code 32

Please guide me as to why this is happening.

I also verified that the nodejs app is actually working by using auth tokes and secret generated from the twitter website and it works. So I have narrowed down that, there is something I am doing wrong in using fabric sdk in the android app.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering it Myself.

Found out that when we configure Fabric it create a new Twitter App for us that is not visible on the [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com) but is Accessible on [fabric.io](http://fabric.io) .

Just had to use these correct App Credentials to get it working